# FTPS MoveIt can't download files with no extension - Not a plain file -

Tags: box, ftps, moveit

I am trying to download files from BOX.com which have no file extension. The batch code looks like this

```
ftps -e:tls-p -a -user:AAAAA@mBBBB.com -password:ABCDE ftp.box.com 
lcd D:\AAFTP\TO_AABB\
cd ABC
binary
prompt
mget *.*
quit
```

Error:

```
200 Command PBSZ okay.
200 Command PROT okay.
215 UNIX Type: L8
ftp> Invalid command.
ftp> Local directory now D:\AAFTP\TO_AABB\.
ftp> 250 Directory changed to /ABC
ftp> 200 Command TYPE okay.
ftp> Interactive mode Off .
ftp> 200 Command TYPE okay.
227 Entering Passive Mode (108,153,27,221,115,207)
150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
ftp: 7 bytes received in 0.31Seconds 0.02Kbytes/sec.
226 Closing data connection.
200 Command TYPE okay.
227 Entering Passive Mode (108,153,27,221,73,102)
550 /ABC: Not a plain file.
227 Entering Passive Mode (108,153,27,221,104,70)
550 /: Not a plain file.
ftp> 221 Goodbye.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you do it to get files without an extension

```
ftps -e:tls-p -a -user:AAAAA@mBBBB.com -password:ABCDE ftp.box.com 
lcd D:\AAFTP\TO_AABB\
cd ABC
prompt
mget
```